# Perl: Best practice for package-wide eval error handling

Tags: perl, error-handling, try-catch, autoload

When working with a Perl (CPAN) module, I often find that I want to implement error handling the same way for all method calls (eg, auto-retry for certain error codes, log some, die on others...).  The code ends up looking very repetitive:

```
my $result1 = eval{
  $obj->method1 ( @arg );
};
if ( $@ )
{
  # error handling code
}

my $result2 = eval{
  $obj->method2 ( @arg );
};
if ( $@ )
{
  # error handling code
}
```

Is there a way to automate this?
One way that seems to work is using a sub{}:

```
sub error_handler
{
  my $method = shift;
  my $result = eval{ shift()->$method ( @_ ); };
  if ( $@ )
  {
    # error handling code
  }
  else
  {
    return ( $result );
  }
}

my $result1 = error_handler ( 'method1', $obj, @arg );
my $result2 = error_handler ( 'method2', $obj, @arg );
```

But I still find this code tedious.  Another idea I had was to try to extend the package:

```
package My::Package;
use Moo;
extends 'Package';

our $AUTOLOAD;
sub AUTOLOAD
{
  $AUTOLOAD =~ s/^My::Package:://;
  my $result = eval{ no strict 'refs'; shift()->$AUTOLOAD ( @_ ); };

  if ( $@ )
  {
    # error handling code
  }
  else
  {
    return ( $result );
  }
}
```

But this code doesn't work - I would need a way to only AUTOLOAD public methods this way.  Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: `AUTOLOAD` will only be called if a called method doesn't exist -- either in the class itself or in any of its base classes

Comment: Is `Package` your own module, or a standard CPAN item? If it's your own then it seems counter-productive to `die` from inside the methods when you want to handle the error yourself. Much better to return an error status, such as `$obj->method1( @arg ) or #error handling code`

Comment: @Borodin: In my testing, the AUTOLOAD gets called, but it gets called recursively, so ... blah.  And as I mentioned, these are CPAN modules (eg, Image::Magick, Net::Twitter, ...) that have many many methods using the same error handling strategy (though unfortunately, not standardized between modules).

Answer (score 2):

Your first method is the best.  Or you might doe a slightly prettier variation with [Try](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Try-0.03/lib/Try.pm) or [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~perigrin/HTTP-Thin-UserAgent-0.011/local/lib/perl5/Try/Tiny.pm), which both approach the reduction in verbosity of your second method.

The main reason to avoid your second and third methods have less to do with the verbosity of your code (which I admit is annoying in the first method), and more to do with the *readability* of your code.

If you end up extending every class you import, your code will be virtually completely unreadable to anyone else, or worse: It will *appear* to be readable ("Oh, I know how MIME::Parse works!"), but won't do what's expected ("Hmm, why isn't MIME::Parse failing with this bad input?")

Your second method has essentially the same problem, but at least it doesn't pretend not to do error handling.  But it still makes debugging much harder.

I know that re-typing the same error handling code frequently is annoying (I do it allllll the time!), but it is the best practice.

Comment: Just to note that the package would be called My::MIME::Parse, so developers would have a clue that something is amiss (sub-classing is not uncommon).  However, I think that implementing it successfully involves some symbol table manipulation so I had the wrong approach.  Anyways, glad to know I'm not the only one who finds it tedious.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg: Sure, but you may receive a My::MIME::Parse object as a reference, and not realize it's not a MIME::Parse object. This of course depends on the context in which these things are used.

Comment: Nowadays, Try::Tiny is best used only with code to run on older perls. As of perl 5.36, there is a native `try` syntax, and you can use it all the way back to 5.14 via Feature::Compat::Try.